# I want to improve the error message on the information registration screen

Tags: reactjs, user-interface

I'm using Material-UI in React to create a web form.

I'm using Material-UI in React to create a web form.
I would like to improve the "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')" error message that appears in components / Questionnaire.js
I've done a lot of research, but I'm stuck in a situation where I don't know how to implement it.
Please give me some advice.

Expected  behaviour

I would like to improve the "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')" error message that appears in components /  Questionnaire.js

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import { Grid } from "@mui/material";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Content from "./components/Content";

function App() {
  return (
    <Grid container direction="column">
      <Header />
      <div style={{ padding: 30 }}>
        <Content />
      </div>
    </Grid>
  );
}
export default App;
```

src / components  / contents.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid } from "@mui/material";
import Stepper from "@mui/material/Stepper";
import Step from "@mui/material/Step";
import StepLabel from "@mui/material/StepLabel";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Basic from "./Basic";
import Questionnaire from "./Questionnaire";
import Optional from "./Optional";
import Confirm from "./Confirm";

const QUESTIONS = [
  "現在、生命保険に加入されていますか？",
  "現在、入院中ですか。また、3ヶ月以内に医師の診察・検査の結果、入院・手術をすすめられたことがありますか？",
  "過去、5年以内に病気やケガで手術を受けたことまたは継続して７日以上の入院をしたことはありますか？",
];
function getSteps() {
  return ["お客様の情報を入力してください", "以下にお答えください", "ご相談ください","内容をご確認ください"];
}
const StepContent = ({ stepIndex }) => {
  switch (stepIndex) {
    case 0:
      return <Basic />;
    case 1:
      return <Questionnaire />;
    case 2:
      return <Optional />;
    case 3:
      return <Confirm />;
    default:
      return "Unknown stepIndex";
  }
};
function Content() {
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const [answers, setAnswers] = React.useState(Array(QUESTIONS.length).fill(null));
  const steps = getSteps();
  const handleNext = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
  };
  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
  };
  const handleReset = () => {
    setActiveStep(0);
  };
  const buttonDisabled = activeStep === 1 && answers.some((a) => !a);
  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid sm={2} />
      <Grid lg={8} sm={8} spacing={10}>
        <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} alternativeLabel>
          {steps.map((label) => (
            <Step key={label}>
              <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
            </Step>
          ))}
        </Stepper>
        {activeStep === steps.length ? (
          <div>
            <Typography>全ステップの表示を完了</Typography>
            <Button onClick={handleReset}>リセット</Button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <Typography>
              <StepContent stepIndex={activeStep} questionnaireProps={{ answers, setAnswers }} />
            </Typography>
            <Button disabled={activeStep === 0} onClick={handleBack}>
              戻る
            </Button>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleNext} disabled={buttonDisabled}>
              {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? "送信" : "次へ"}
            </Button>
          </div>
        )}
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
export default Content;
```

src / components  / Questionnaire.js

```
import React from "react";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Radio from "@mui/material/Radio";
import RadioGroup from "@mui/material/RadioGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import FormLabel from "@mui/material/FormLabel";

const Questionnaire = ({ answers, setAnswers }) => {
  const handleAnswer = (answeredIndex, answer) => {
    setAnswers(answers.map((e, i) => (i === answeredIndex ? answer : e)));
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl component="fieldset">
        {answers
          .filter((_, i) => i === 0 || answers[i - 1])
          .map((answer, i) => (
            <React.Fragment key={i}>
              <FormLabel component="legend">{Questionnaire[i]}</FormLabel>
              {answer ? (
                <Typography>{answer === "yes" ? "はい" : "いいえ"}</Typography>
              ) : (
                <RadioGroup
                  row
                  aria-label="gender"
                  name="row-radio-buttons-group"
                  onChange={(_evt, value) => {
                    handleAnswer(i, value);
                  }}
                >
                  <FormControlLabel value="yes" control={<Radio />} label="はい" />
                  <FormControlLabel value="no" control={<Radio />} label="いいえ" />
                </RadioGroup>
              )}
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Questionnaire;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to "Improve the error message", those errors should never happen in your app, you should fix them.

In this case it says that you are trying to access a property (`filters` in this case) of `undefined`.

This means that in `Questionnaire.js`, the `answer` prop is `undefined`. You are not passing that prop in `contents.js`:

```js
    case 1:
      return <Questionnaire />;
```